# Book id: 90's YA horror anthology series, not Goosebumps?

Tags: story-identification, young-adult, horror

The only book I remember with any clarity had a very mean-looking satyr climbing out of a well on the cover. His eyes were red and his smile disturbed me as a child. All I remember about the story itself was that there was a well in the town, the ending had the main character being tricked into being the new person/thing/whatever stuck in the well, and I get the feeling the story didn't take place in "modern" times. If anyone has any ideas I would really appreciate them. I've been searching for years, and it's driving me nuts!! :[

Comment: Have you looked through the "Related" list here to the right? Could it be one of those?